# UpdateView in Django shows blank forms instead of Database previous data

Tags: python, html, mysql, django, forms

I'm using UpdateView to edit data using forms.

After I click to edit the `popup` using modal is showing the forms with blank data! It doesn't retrieve the previous data that was in the Database.
Anyone know what should I add?

I am stuck with this edit for about a week :(

If anyone has a clue I will be grateful! 
Thank you!

view.py-

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, UpdateView, DeleteView, CreateView
from DevOpsWeb.forms import HomeForm
from DevOpsWeb.models import serverlist
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from simple_search import search_filter
from django.db.models import Q
class HomeView(TemplateView):

template_name = 'serverlist.html'


def get(self, request):
    form = HomeForm()
    query = request.GET.get("q")
    posts = serverlist.objects.all()

    if query:
        posts = serverlist.objects.filter(Q(ServerName__icontains=query) | Q(Owner__icontains=query) | Q(Project__icontains=query) | Q(Description__icontains=query) | Q(IP__icontains=query) | Q(ILO__icontains=query) | Q(Rack__icontains=query))
    else:
        posts = serverlist.objects.all()
    args = {'form' : form, 'posts' : posts}
    return render(request, self.template_name, args)

def post(self,request):
    form = HomeForm(request.POST)
    posts = serverlist.objects.all()



    if form.is_valid(): # Checks if validation of the forms passed
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        #if not form.cleaned_data['ServerName']:
        #post.servername = " "
        post.save()
        #text = form.cleaned_data['ServerName']
        form = HomeForm()
        return redirect('serverlist')
args = {'form': form,  'text' : text}
return render(request, self.template_name,args)


class PostDelete(DeleteView):
    model = serverlist
    success_url = reverse_lazy('serverlist')

class PostEdit(UpdateView):
    model = serverlist
    #post = serverlist.objetcs.get(server_id=server_id)
    fields = ['ServerName','Owner','Project','Description','IP','ILO','Rack','Status']
    success_url=reverse_lazy('serverlist')
```

urls.py -

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from DevOpsWeb.views import HomeView
from DevOpsWeb.views import PostDelete
from DevOpsWeb.views import PostEdit
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view(), name='serverlist'),

     url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
     #DevOpsWeb:8000/Delete/
     url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', PostDelete.as_view(), name="delete_post"),
     url(r'^django_popup_view_field/', include('django_popup_view_field.urls', namespace="django_popup_view_field")),
     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
     #DevOpsWeb:8000/edit/
     url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', PostEdit.as_view(), name="edit_post"),
]
```

forms.py -

```
from django import forms
from DevOpsWeb.models import serverlist


class HomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ServerName = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput,max_length = 30,required=False)
    Owner = forms.CharField(max_length = 50,required=False)
    Project = forms.CharField(max_length = 30,required=False)
    Description = forms.CharField(max_length = 255,required=False)
    IP = forms.CharField(max_length = 30,required=False)
    ILO = forms.CharField(max_length = 30,required=False)
    Rack = forms.CharField(max_length = 30,required=False)
    Status = forms.CharField(max_length = 30,required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = serverlist
        fields = ('ServerName' ,'Owner','Project','Description','IP','ILO','Rack','Status',)

class AutoCompleteModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    widget = forms.TextInput
def clean(self, value):
    value = super(AutoCompleteModelChoiceField, self).clean(value)
    return value


class serverForm(forms.ModelForm):
    hotel = AutoCompleteModelChoiceField(queryset=serverlist.objects.all())
```

index.html (The part with the edit button)-

```
            <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-sm" id="Edit{{server.id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title">Edit Server <b>{{ server.ServerName }}</b> </h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                        </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                        <form action="{% url 'edit_post' server.id %}" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
                                <!--<center>    {{ form.as_p }} </center> -->
                                                        {% for field in form %}
                                                                <div class="fieldWrapper">
                                                {{ field.errors }}
                                                                        <!-- {{ field.label_tag }} -->

                                <small><b>{{ field.html_name }}<p align="left"></b> {{ field }}</small> </p>

                                                {% if field.help_text %}
                                                <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
                                                {% endif %}

                                                        </div>


                                {% endfor %}
                </div>
                <div class="wrapper">
                &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                <h2><button type="submit" class="save btn btn-success btn-lg">Confirm</button></h2>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                                <h2><button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button></h2>
                </div>
                </form>
            </td>
                </div>
        </tr>
                {% endfor %}
```

The posts and the edit button:

```
                {% for server in posts %}

        <tr>
          <div class ="server">
            <td></td>
            <td><center>{{ server.ServerName }}</center></td>
            <td><center>{{ server.Owner }}</center></td>
            <td><center>{{ server.Project }}</center></td>
            <td><center>{{ server.Description }}</center></td>
            <td><center>{{ server.IP }}</center></td>
            <td><center>{{ server.ILO }}</center></td>
            <td><center>{{ server.Rack }}</center></td>
            <td><h4><span class="badge badge-success">{{ server.Status }}</span></h4></td></center>

            <td>

&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-toggle="modal" href="#delete-server-{{server.id}}"
             data-target="#Del{{server.id}}">Delete <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>&nbsp
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="modal" href="#edit-server-{{server.id}}"
             data-target="#Edit{{server.id}}"> &nbsp&nbspEdit&nbsp           <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
&nbsp


                        <div id ="Del{{server.id}}" class="modal fade" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-dialog" id="delete-server-{{server.id}}">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h5 class="modal-title">Delete Confirmation</h5>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                        <form action="{% url 'delete_post' server.id %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                                            <h6>Are you sure you want to delete {{ server.ServerName }}?</h6>
                                                <br>
                                            <center><input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" value="Confirm"/>
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button></center>

                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>


                        </div>
            </div>




            <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-sm" id="Edit{{server.id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title">Edit Server <b>{{ server.ServerName }}</b> </h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                        </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                        <form action="{% url 'edit_post' server.id %}" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
                                <!--<center>    {{ form.as_p }} </center> -->
                                                        {% for field in form %}
                                                                <div class="fieldWrapper">
                                                {{ field.errors }}
                                                                        <!-- {{ field.label_tag }} -->

                                <small><b>{{ field.html_name }}<p align="left"></b> {{ field }}</small> </p>

                                                {% if field.help_text %}
                                                <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
                                                {% endif %}

                                                        </div>


                                {% endfor %}
                </div>
                <div class="wrapper">
                &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                <h2><button type="submit" class="save btn btn-success btn-lg">Confirm</button></h2>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                                <h2><button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button></h2>
                </div>
                </form>
            </td>
                </div>
        </tr>
                {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</h5>
    </table>
```

Comment: Don't really understand your `views.py`: Where's the class `HomeView`? Your `get()` and `post()` functions are not inside a class...

Comment: Are you actually trying to embed multiple `PostEdit` views inside your general `HomeView`?

Comment: The function get and post is under HomeView class.
And I don't under the second question :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not initializing your form with the instance that you want to update:

```
form = HomeForm()
```

instead when you want to have a form filled with the data from an object:

```
form = HomeForm(instance=my_object_to_update)
```

Since you want to do this for every `post` you display in your `HomeView`, you need to initialize a different form for every `post`. In `HomeView.get()` and in `HomeView.post()` method, in addition to creating the empty `HomeForm()` that's used for creating a new `serverlist`:

```
for post in posts:
    forms[post.id] = HomeForm(instance=post)
```

And in your template render (assuming your loop `{% for server in posts %}`)

```
{% with server.id as id %}
    {% with forms|get_by_key:id as edit_form %}
        <form action="{% url 'edit_post' server.id %}" method="post">
           ... display the form: your current code {% for field in edit_form %} etc...
        </form> 
    {% endwith %}
{% endwith %}
```

I'm using a custom template filter `|get_by_key:variable` to get the dict value by key when using a variable:

```
@register.filter(name='get_by_key')
def get_by_key(dictionnary, key):
"""Return element in dictionnary corresponding to `key`."""
    return dictionnary[key] if isinstance(dictionnary, dict) else ''
```

Since you have one template to create a new serverlist but also to show all the existing serverlist objects and uptdate them, you need both kinds of forms. So creating the `forms` dict above is *in addition* to having the creation form `HomeForm()`. Your context should have:

```
args = {
    'form': form,  # this is the serverlist creation form (empty)
    'forms': forms,  # these are all the forms for existing instances
    'posts': posts}
```

Also I don't see where in your `PostEdit` you specify your `form_class`, this is needed for an `UpdateView` to work.

Comment: under form_class I wrote:  form_class = HomeForm

And the : for post in posts:
Do I need to write it in the post function or in the PostEdit class?

And the template render I should write it in the modal in the serverlist.html?

Comment: There are two form = HomeForm()..
One in the first line under post and one in the if form_is_valid()
Which one should I change and put the for loop?

Comment: Where should I add this lines in my templalte?

Since now it shows the data for only the first form
{% with post.id as id %}
    {% with forms.id as form %}
        do something with {{ form }}
    {% endwith %}
{% endwith %}

Comment: I'm assuming you're looping through your `posts` somewhere: `{% for post in posts %} ... code to display your post and its edit form ... here you add the template code I mentioned ... {% endfor %}`

Comment: I added the short code of the posts I loop in the html in the table in the main question in the end...
Can you edit in your answer exactly where I should add the html code to pass the form id? and also what is "do something? " do what? I just need to pass the form id no?

Comment: "do something with form" means render the form: this is all the code you already have with the edit button. Just wrap the outer `<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-sm" id="Edit{{server.id}}">` that contains all the code to render your edit form with what I showed. Except you're using `server.id` instead of `post.id` in your for loop.

Comment: {% for field in form %}
{% with post.id as id %}
    {% with forms.id as form %}
..... my code?
    {% endwith %}
{% endwith %}

Can you please show in my code how to edit my serverlist.html? It really confuse me :)

Comment: no, `{% for field in form %}` should refer to the specific form, you need to define `form` correctly before that.

Comment: global name 'forms' is not defined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159994/discussion-between-eilon-ashkenazi-and-dirkgroten).